# Custom Module using Bonfire CI on Cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, bonfire

I have developed my own module using bonfire on CI. The application works best locally. When I deploy it on Cpanel, the main pages until login screen work well.
As soon as I try to hit the pages of my module, it gives me a 404 error. They are of the pattern: `http://website.com/admin/content/blog/edit` etc.

I have edited .htaccess in the root directory, but I am not sure what to put in .htaccess in Bonfire_root/public. I suspect the problem lies here but I am unable to troubleshoot successfully.

Comment: which version of CI are you using?

Comment: I am using version3.

Comment: It may be case sensitive issue. Locally it works fine but doesnt work on server. Use capital letter for controller.

Comment: Which controller? Content or the custom one?

Comment: custom one. If not worked apply on both.

Comment: No it still does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133961/discussion-between-nishant-nair-and-ralph).

Comment: Sure this sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nishant-nair mentioned, the solution was to Capitalize the first character of the controller file names.